# Unable to execute queries in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm an Oracle DBA that's been asked to do some work on SQL Server 2000.  I've been granted domain access and have installed MS SSMS 2008.  I can access the SQL Server 2000 databases via this tool and see the tables, views, functions, stored procedures, etc.  However, if I try to access the data in the tables or run queries against any of the user tables or system tables I get the following error message.

"Cannot execute script.
Unable to start the Transact-SQL debugger. The Transact-SQL debugger does not support SQL Server 2005 or earlier versions of SQL Server. (SQLEditors)"

I'm assuming it's a permissions problem.  I can where the sysadmin SQL Server Fixed Role is assigned to the BUILTIN\Administrators role.  I've read where administrators - local, domain, etc. - are implicitly assigned to the BUILTIN\Administrators role so I'm not sure why this is not working.

Comment: Do you get the same result when executing the query by selecting Query > Execute from the SSMS menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: don't run the queries through the debugger.  The longer answer has to do with how you're running your queries.  Once you're connected to the server, you should be able to enter your query in a new window and hit the F5 button.  This is the vanilla "execute query" button and shouldn't run any debugging code.

Comment: <grin> I haven't been running my queries through the debugger, but rather, the code editor.  I can't run any queries without getting that error.  No debugging code is running.  From various posts on the web it points to a permissions issue, but I can't tie it to one.  Thanks however, for the reply.

Comment: @5lbBass - the debugger is built into SSMS - you run a query through it by clicking the triangular green "play" button on the SSMS "SQL Editor" toolbar. To execute a query without starting the debugger, click the "! Execute" button (by default just to the left of the debug button)

Comment: Ed has the right of it.  The debugger is built into SSMS.  Does it make sense to you that it would give you an error about the debugger if you weren't running code through it?  Did you at least try my suggestion before saying that it's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Set SQL Server Permissions for Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw a similiar article based on Visual Studio 2010. I'm not using Visual Studio, though, but SSMS 2008, so I'm not sure it appies directly. Nevertheless, I did read and think I'm okay.  My windows account is a domain admin as has the BUILTIN/Administrators role which has the sysadmin role.